# Having a problem calling up a query given the result of a combobox and another combobox

Tags: vba, ms-access

The form is not calling up the query but the queries work when I run them and they show the correct results.

Please see my code to call up the queries

```vb
If Me.PartsStatus.Value = "Parts Arrived" And Me.Combo156.Value = "No" Then
    Me.RecordSource = "ServiceListPrtArr"
ElseIf Me.PartsStatus.Value = "Parts Arrived" And Me.Combo156.Value = "Yes" Then
    Me.RecordSource = "ServiceListPrtArrGone"
End If
```

Trying to call up two different reports from the results of an item listed in the combobox and items listed from a second combobox.

Comment: Can you confirm the exact text of the combobox values? That is, just before the IF statement, debug or popup a dialog showing the values of those two combboxes.

Comment: Set a breakpoint on `If` and when the execution stops there, inspect the involved values. E.g. you can type `?Me.Combo156.Value` + *Enter* into the immediate window (open it with *Ctrl-G*) or add the these expressions to the Watch window.

Comment: What does "calling up the query" mean? I see an attempt to set a RecordSource property - assume for a form. So why do you mention "call up two different reports" if issue is with form? Is Combo156 UNBOUND? Is its value text "Yes/No" or Boolean Yes/No? Instead of building two reports, looks like could just apply filter criteria to one report when opening. Possibly same could be done to form - apply filter instead of changing RecordSource.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I have come right. Advise was useful. Thanks. Need to read up about the values of Booloean functions. But thanks alot.